# Excel VBA Text File Import Is Blank

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I am trying to import 800+ text files into their own worksheets within the same workbook. Code for that is below:

```
Public Sub dImport()
nFile = Dir("R:\O21DIR\*.txt")

Do While nFile <> vbNullString

Set ws3 = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
Application.CutCopyMode = False

With ws3.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & nFile, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = nFile
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlFixedWidth
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 9, 2, 9, 2, 9, 9, 9)
    .TextFileFixedColumnWidths = Array(21, 16, 10, 13, 17, 3, 14, 7, 5, 12, 5, 6)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
End With

ws3.Name = nFile
For cnt = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count To 1 Step -1
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(cnt).Delete
Next
For cnt = ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Count To 1 Step -1
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Item(cnt).Delete
Next
nFile = Dir
fRefine
Loop
End Sub
```

I get no errors, but I also get NOTHING on the sheet. The worksheet is created and named correctly. And the text file DOES have data in it. The data import code was pulled from recording a macro, so it DID work at one point.

I did delete the `.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False` because I was getting an Error 1004.

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Using Excel 2016 on Office 365 32-bit. I've tried this on 2 different systems with the same software setup. Same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a subject matter expert, but by looking at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytables.add), I think you should add a `Refresh` somewhere.

Pasted from above page:

```
Set shFirstQtr = Workbooks(1).Worksheets(1) 
Set qtQtrResults = shFirstQtr.QueryTables.Add( _ 
    Connection := "TEXT;C:\My Documents\19980331.txt", _
    Destination := shFirstQtr.Cells(1,1)) 
With qtQtrResults 
    .TextFileParsingType = xlFixedWidth 
    .TextFileFixedColumnWidths := Array(5,4) 
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes := _ 
        Array(xlTextFormat, xlSkipColumn, xlGeneralFormat) 
    .Refresh 
End With
```

Comment: When I had the refresh in there I got a Run-Time Error 1004 "Excel Cannot Find The Text File To Refresh This External Data Range". That is why there was no Refresh in there.